# Any Github Project with Spring MVC + JSP+ Tiles + Bootstrap Framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I have done Spring MVC and JSP development before, I am learning Tiles and Bootstrap at moment, is there a project(s) demonstrate the usage in the combination of Spring and Tiles in Github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply use bootstap.css and bootstrap.js JSP pages with jQuery.js for your ajax data
if you google, you can find a lot of sample for starting,
I find two links for you, I hope them help you.

ex1: [springmvc-bootstrap](https://github.com/priyatam/springmvc-bootstrap)

ex2: [SpringMvcStepByStep](https://github.com/in28minutes/SpringMvcStepByStep)