# Spring app stops reading css and js files

Tags: javascript, html, css, spring

I'm new in developing spring mvc application. I get some html theme from the internet and attached to my project. At the begining everythig works fine but after some deployment to tomcat it stops showing styles etc. And now I'm stuck with this. I downloaded directly js scripts to my project and it stil doesn't work. Do anybody knows how to solve it? I'm using Intellij to develop this app, it is possible that IDE cache data in some way? When I open theme directly in browser it works perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Currently, this question is blatantly off-topic. You need to add the code and more details about what you have and what does not work. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you can find some information of how to ask a good question.

Comment: take a look at to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44700551/any-github-project-with-spring-mvc-jsp-tiles-bootstrap-framework/44709976#44709976